# Background html

Tags: html, css, background

I would like to have a picture as a background. I've written it in my CSS stylesheet as following:

```
body {
  backgroung-image: url('link to my picture');
  width: 600px; 
}
```

When looking at this in the browser I see maybe a fifth of it since it is so big. Is my width property doing anything in the code above? How can I adjust the size of the picture so it fits the HTML element?

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: The width of your statement is defining the width of the body in its entirety, NOT the width of the background image.

Comment: That, and you have a typo `backgroung-image:` should be `background-image`

Comment: I would suggest you change the size of you picture (using Photoshop or another image manipulation software) to be the size you need it to be.

Comment: I have edited my answer to make it more clear to you.

Answer (score 2):

Use **background-size: cover;** to make the background-image cover the whole body element.

```
body{
        background: url('http://placehold.it/350x150') no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
}
```

**Note:** I have used `no-repeat` because the default value for `background-repeat:` is `repeat;`.

If this syntax makes more sense to you then can use this one as well:

```
body{
        background: url('http://placehold.it/350x150');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
    }
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/puakv13x/

Comment: I did this and now the width is okey, but vertially I can not see the entire picture, how do I handle that?

Comment: @BjornRunow You might need to change from "cover" to "contain", or if you don't mind stretching "100% 100%". As for the "no repeat", it just forces the background not to be repeated(only appliciable if image is smaller than view)

Comment: You can also adapt background-position: center center; for example

Comment: I'm not sure because I should see your design and code to tell you what to apply :)

Comment: @VelocityHD Thanks for your answer. I tried stretching it but does not look so good. Now I understand what the "No repeat" means :)

Comment: About "no-repeat" which has been added to my code, that is because the default value for "background-repeat" is "repeat" and that's why if you don't want your background to be repeated you need to use "no-repeat".

Comment: I have edited my answer to make it more clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a spelling error (`backgroung-image: url('link to my picture')`) this should be changed to `background-image: url('link to my picture')`.

The answer to your question

> How can I adjust the size of the picture so it fits the HTML element?

Do this by adding a `background-size:contain`. You can also define how many pixels you want it to be; `background-size: 150px 100px` the numbers are (x, y).
It may also be required adding a `background-repeat: no-repeat` if image is not scaled.

Take a look at this site: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have not yet understood what the "no repeat" command does, please explain that if you have time. I changed to background-size: 600px 200px but then it became too small. <br> Do I have to "guess" how many pixels wide and tall it should be to get it perfect? I tried putting 100% but then only the width was perfect and I saw about 75% vertically.

Comment: I'd humbly request to stop linking to w3schools. It contains lots of outdated and misleading information.

Comment: @TJ I do know of the fact with outdated material, but the page really describes stuff well for "newbies" who just started with web development. I suppose it's good using it very early, but when we reach a certain point, we start to learn from newer and more advanced sources. Not long ago, i was in BjornRunow's place, w3schools helped me a lot in the beginning

Comment: @BjornRunow Don't forget marking an answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

in your *style.css*, or in your *index.html*;

```
body {
  background-image: url("paper.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```